# How to do "greater than or equal" operation on time objects in go?

Tags: datetime, go

How do I write something like this in go?

```
if time.Now() >= expiry {
}
```

If I use `time.Now().After(expiry)`, then it is not really the greater than or equal (`>=`) logic that I am looking for. If I use `time.Now().After(expiry) || time.Now() == expiry`, then the expression looks long. Is there a "proper" way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The proper way is:

```
now:=time.Now()
if now.After(expiry) || now.Equal(expiry) {
  ...
}
```

Or

```
if !time.Now().Before(expiry) {
  ...
}
```